# How to check if text has certain format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check if text/string has `(number:number-number)`  format in Python?

An example is `(7:10-9)`

I think I need to use Regex?

Comment: Lev's regex will solve your problem nicely.  To develop regexes on your own, try using http://txt2re.com

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that would be the easiest. Example:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.match('\(\d+:\d+-\d+\)', '(7:10-9)')
Out[2]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x24655e0>

In [3]: re.match('\(\d+:\d+-\d+\)', '(7)')

In [4]:
```

As a function:

```
def match(s):
    return bool(re.match('\(\d+:\d+-\d+\)', s))
```

Don't forget to look through [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).